# apache2 reverse proxy / port forwarding issues

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a (node/react/redux) webapp that runs on 4 ports: a backend server runs on 4050, and three client app pieces run from 3000, 4000, and 5000. (Running on AWS, Ubuntu 16.04)

NGINX port forwarding using reverse proxy works great. But my org is used to Apache, and Apache plays better with our SAML2 SSO system which I would like to use.

I've gotten redirections to work, as in

```
RewriteRule   "^/client1$" "http://my.aws.ip.addr:3000/" [R]
RewriteRule   "^/client2$" "http://my.aws.ip.addr:4000/" [R]
RewriteRule   "^/client3$" "http://my.aws.ip.addr:5000/" [R]
```

in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. I can't seem to get any other suggestions to work. For example, VirtualHost declarations. I would prefer the "aesthetic" of VirtualHost-based proxying, and would like to understand why I can't port forward from urls like `http://my.aws.ip.addr/client1`.

A sample VirtualHost that doesn't work:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  ServerName my.aws.ip.addr/client1
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy *>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass /client1/ http://my.aws.ip.addr:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse /client1/ http://my.aws.ip.addr:3000/
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

(Doesn't work at `*:80` either)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the path from the ServerName :

```
ServerName my.aws.ip.addr
```

This line should be filled by a domain only : it indicates Apache which domain request should trigger this configuration.

Otherwise the configuration seems fine.